# The counts for questions and answers in the accounts tab all display 0

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-accounts, network-profile

Last time I check overall counters, there was something strange:

While https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/ display:

> 138 Answers
> 27,469 Reputation
> 15 Questions

The *overall page* https://stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=accounts display:

> Meta Stack Overflow ♦
>
> Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites
> Joined 4 years ago, last seen 2 days ago
> 228,907 reputation
> 64 621 1052 badges
> 0 questions
> 0 answers
>
> Stack Overflow ♦
>
> Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers
> Joined 5 years ago, last seen 2 days ago
> 27,469 reputation
> 36 112 125 badges
> 0 questions
> 0 answers
>
> Super User ♦
>
> Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users
> Joined 4 years ago, last seen 2 days ago
> 11,742 reputation
> 19 64 98 badges
> 0 questions
> 0 answers
>
> Webmasters ♦
>
> Q&A for pro webmasters
> Joined 3 years ago, last seen 9 days ago
> 7,916 reputation
> 12 45 71 badges
> 0 questions
> 0 answers

Notice, all Question and Answer counters display `0`.

Comment: [this is really weird](http://stackexchange.com/users/1266491/doorknob?tab=accounts) ([screenshot for posterity](http://i.imgur.com/l14Myhh.png))

Answer (score 12):

Well, this sucks! Unfortunately we're not in a position to fix it, yet.  What I can do is a very close approximation which I've just done and you'll begin to see as cache falls out over the next 10 minutes.

Since the last import of an SE 1.0 site (we're sure this time, we deleted the servers, always double tap!) we needed to run a network-wide aggregation backfill which syncs up our aggregated data from all sites.  Yesterday we ran only the user portion of this without considering those counts...which are traditionally synced by the next step in the process.

The reason we can't do that is it creates a huge amount of data churn we don't want to risk at the moment. While [we have our secondary Oregon data center offline](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/61406501712/datacenter-maintenance-sep-16-20-2013) our database transaction logs are accumulating in New York, any large scale data changes greatly impact that.  While we have plenty of SSD space these days, it's still limited so we want to avoid a backfill until Oregon SQL instances are online and re-syncing with New York, draining that transaction log queue down to 0 again.

We anticipate this process happening Thursday or Friday this week, [Steve](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1233/steven-murawski) and [Geoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) are working out there to bring the upgraded data center back online as soon as superhumanly possibly.